# How does java class keep information about generic type?

Tags: java, generics

As i understand it correctly, java performs type erasure, where `T` in

```
class Test<T>{
  private T something;

}
```

becomes object. However why in this example:

```
class Test<T>{
   private Object[] arr;
   private int index = 0;

   Test(){ arr = new Object[10];)

   public void put(T el) {
       arr[index++] = el;
   } 

}

Test<String> test = new Test();
test.put(10)
```

triggers compilation error and requires argument to put be String, when during compilation `T` becomes `Object`?

Comment: Because that is what type erasure is: during compile time T is checked and verified and then erased.

Comment: `test.put(10)` -> how you wrote `10` mean it's integer and you test accept only string. And `T` don't become `Object` after compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After compilation `T` erases to `Object` (in this case, since there's no upper bound for template parameter `T`). During compilation your invalid code is detected and a compile-time error occurs.

Otherwise the whole mechanism would be completely useless, why use `T` if it would actually be `Object` at all times?

Comment: so type erasure happens after whole code is compiled and checked.. thanks